# Why is touchpad scrolling in Firefox and other Win32 programs hyper fast? With a Surface Pro 3 type cover

Tags: touchpad, scrolling, microsoft-surface-pro-3

Using the touchpad on my Surface Pro 3 type cover, two-finger scrolling in Firefox and some other programs is completely unusable because moving my finger half a millimetre scrolls down three pages.

In Edge, Explorer, and all Metro apps, two-finger scrolling is normal, but scrolling in Firefox and many other Win32 programs is unusable. Wheel scrolling with a regular mouse is normal everywhere.

This has been a problem for a very long time (years), but I have never been able to figure out why, nor have I found anyone else with this problem. I've gotten used to scrolling with the keyboard and the touch screen, but it's very annoying. I've re-installed Windows from scratch at least once, but nothing changed. None of the touchpad or mouse settings change this behaviour. If I change the "lines per scroll" option to 1, scrolling in Firefox et al. becomes *usable* although still too fast, but scrolling everywhere else is waaay too slow.

**Why is two-finger scrolling so dysfunctional in Win32 programs using the touchpad (trackpad) on my Surface Pro 3, and how can I fix it?**

Comment: I personally have a Surface Pro 3, and I never had this problem, which version of the type cover are you using?

Comment: I bought it with my SP3 in January 2015. The model number is 1644 and it also has the numbers N1364 and Z396 on it. But I don't see how it could be a hardware issue, because it works flawlessly in Universal apps and in Explorer. Perhaps it's a driver issue, and there is more than one driver for these keyboards? I don't know how I'd figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. The buggy scrolling behaviour is caused by the [Logitech Options](https://support.logitech.com/en_us/software/options) software that I use to customise the buttons on my Logitech mouse. Uninstalling Logitech Options (or disabling it in the Start-up tab of Task Manager) then rebooting solves the problem.

I'm glad I have a functional touch pad now, but it's unfortunate that I can't customise my mouse buttons anymore. Oh well.